# oauth2client throwing AttributeError when run as service

Tags: python, oauth2client

I'm trying to access the google calendar API with a simple python script, running on a raspberry pi.

This script, from the example [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/calendar/quickstart/quickstart.py):

```
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
store = file.Storage('home/pi/brief/token.json')
creds = store.get()
```

..works fine when running from command line, but when running as a service (systemctl) it exits, saying:

```
python[27500]:     store = file.Storage('home/pi/brief/token.json')
python[27500]: AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'Storage'
```

I must be missing something fundamental here. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Python is this? In 2.7, `file` was a builtin. It's surprising that `from oauth2client import file` doesn't mask it but I'm just curious if it might be an issue

Comment: yes, python 2.7. Agree it is strange, and why does it differ when running as service? I want to emphasize it works fine when just running from command line.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled oauth2client and reconfigured the service, now it works. Beats me what was wrong. Thank you all for your efforts.